# Why is my Run Length Encoding algorithm not draw things properly to the console?

Tags: c, algorithm, matrix, console, ascii

So I have made an RLE implementation to draw characters to the console from a matrix but for some reason, the `print_chars();` function seems to be overprinting the ammount of characters that sould be displayed, I am only making 8 values in the matrix bigger than 0 but it is printing like 30. I believe this could be due to allocating too much memory but I dont know. Any help would be apreciated.

code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <windows.h>

#define sizeX 150
#define sizeY 40

int grid[sizeY][sizeX];

void colorChar(int r, int g, int b){
    printf("\x1b[48;2;%d;%d;%dm",r,g,b);
}

void draw_screen(){
 int y, x;
 for(y=0;y<sizeY;y++){
  for(x=0;x<sizeX;x++){
    if(grid[y][x] == 0){
        colorChar(0,0,0);
    printf(" ");
   }
   else{
    colorChar(255,255,255);
    printf(" ");
   }
  }
  printf("\n");
 }
}

int main(void) {
 int x, y;
 float frameTime;
 grid[19][19] = 1;
 grid[2][8] = 1;
 grid[15][12] = 1;
 grid[6][3] = 1;
 grid[13][16] = 99;
 grid[17][3] = 1;
 grid[6][6] = 1;
 grid[9][3] = 1;

 clock_t start = clock();
 draw_screen();
 clock_t stop = clock();
 frameTime = (float)(stop - start) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
 printf("Frame: %f\n", frameTime);
}
```

Comment: Why do you `#include <windows.h>` *twice*? Including one time unconditionally.

Comment: As for one major problem, you can't compare strings using `==`. Since both `color` and e.g. `"GREEN"` will be pointers, the comparison compares the actual pointers. And in almost all cases they just won't be equal. With that said, since you seem to pass only literal strings to `print_chars` then that comparison will most likely work (assuming that the compiler only creates one single instance of all literal string, which it actually doesn't have to do). But don't get used to that behavior, use `strcmp` to compare strings!

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude sorry, I was using it cuz the sleep(); function does'nt really work for me. Also sorryfor the comparison, will change it next time.

Comment: I gave you a working version of code that did this, a few weeks ago, when the grid was smaller. It output a flag character marking where you would invoke the "colour change" rather than outputting a character. Now you've posted a bounty to fix code that doesn't keep x v. y straight... Amazing...

Comment: @Fe2O3 Yes but your version does not work ether when given a big matrix ether, also although I apreciate you code, I believe my version is more understandable by my standarts.

Comment: Here's a gift: The largest number of "spaces" output by `print_chars()` would be `(x*y)` (plus a null terminator). Right now that is 6001 bytes (maximum!). Add 100 for the "color escape sequence string", and the buffer is still quite small. Re-use a global 8K buffer instead of thrashing `malloc()` to death... You want speed?

Comment: @Fe2O3, The problem persists even withoust using malloc()

Answer (score 3):

I replaced your calls to `print_chars` with debugging `printf`s:

```
void draw_screen(){
 int y, x;
 for(y=0;y<=sizeY;y++){
  for(x=0;x<=sizeX;x++){
   if(grid[y][x] == 0){
    counter0++;
    if(grid[y][x+1] != 0 || x+1 >= sizeX){
     printf("grid[%d][%d] == 0; grid[%d][%d+1] != 0 || %d+1 >= %d; ", y, x, y, x, x, sizeX);
     printf("x=%d; y=%d; counter0=%d; counter1=%d\n", x, y, counter0, counter1);
     //print_chars(counter0, ' ', "BLACK");
     counter0 = 0;
    }
   }
   else{
    counter1++;
    if(grid[y][x+1] != 1 || x+1 >= sizeX){
     printf("!(grid[%d][%d] == 0); grid[%d][%d+1] != 1 || %d+1 >= %d; ", y, x, y, x, x, sizeX);
     printf("x=%d; y=%d; counter0=%d; counter1=%d\n", x, y, counter0, counter1);
     //print_chars(counter1, ' ', "WHITE");
     counter1 = 0;
    }
   }
  }
  //printf("\n");
 }
}
```

This outputs:

```
grid[0][87] == 0; grid[0][87+1] != 0 || 87+1 >= 150; x=87; y=0; counter0=88; counter1=0
!(grid[0][88] == 0); grid[0][88+1] != 1 || 88+1 >= 150; x=88; y=0; counter0=0; counter1=1
grid[0][149] == 0; grid[0][149+1] != 0 || 149+1 >= 150; x=149; y=0; counter0=61; counter1=0
grid[0][150] == 0; grid[0][150+1] != 0 || 150+1 >= 150; x=150; y=0; counter0=1; counter1=0
grid[1][47] == 0; grid[1][47+1] != 0 || 47+1 >= 150; x=47; y=1; counter0=48; counter1=0
!(grid[1][48] == 0); grid[1][48+1] != 1 || 48+1 >= 150; x=48; y=1; counter0=0; counter1=1
grid[1][149] == 0; grid[1][149+1] != 0 || 149+1 >= 150; x=149; y=1; counter0=101; counter1=0
grid[1][150] == 0; grid[1][150+1] != 0 || 150+1 >= 150; x=150; y=1; counter0=1; counter1=0
grid[2][7] == 0; grid[2][7+1] != 0 || 7+1 >= 150; x=7; y=2; counter0=8; counter1=0
!(grid[2][8] == 0); grid[2][8+1] != 1 || 8+1 >= 150; x=8; y=2; counter0=0; counter1=1
grid[2][149] == 0; grid[2][149+1] != 0 || 149+1 >= 150; x=149; y=2; counter0=141; counter1=0
grid[2][150] == 0; grid[2][150+1] != 0 || 150+1 >= 150; x=150; y=2; counter0=1; counter1=0
grid[3][122] == 0; grid[3][122+1] != 0 || 122+1 >= 150; x=122; y=3; counter0=123; counter1=0
!(grid[3][123] == 0); grid[3][123+1] != 1 || 123+1 >= 150; x=123; y=3; counter0=0; counter1=1
grid[3][125] == 0; grid[3][125+1] != 0 || 125+1 >= 150; x=125; y=3; counter0=2; counter1=0
!(grid[3][126] == 0); grid[3][126+1] != 1 || 126+1 >= 150; x=126; y=3; counter0=0; counter1=1
grid[3][149] == 0; grid[3][149+1] != 0 || 149+1 >= 150; x=149; y=3; counter0=23; counter1=0
grid[3][150] == 0; grid[3][150+1] != 0 || 150+1 >= 150; x=150; y=3; counter0=1; counter1=0
grid[4][82] == 0; grid[4][82+1] != 0 || 82+1 >= 150; x=82; y=4; counter0=83; counter1=0
!(grid[4][83] == 0); grid[4][83+1] != 1 || 83+1 >= 150; x=83; y=4; counter0=0; counter1=1
grid[4][85] == 0; grid[4][85+1] != 0 || 85+1 >= 150; x=85; y=4; counter0=2; counter1=0
!(grid[4][86] == 0); grid[4][86+1] != 1 || 86+1 >= 150; x=86; y=4; counter0=0; counter1=1
grid[4][149] == 0; grid[4][149+1] != 0 || 149+1 >= 150; x=149; y=4; counter0=63; counter1=0
grid[4][150] == 0; grid[4][150+1] != 0 || 150+1 >= 150; x=150; y=4; counter0=1; counter1=0
grid[5][42] == 0; grid[5][42+1] != 0 || 42+1 >= 150; x=42; y=5; counter0=43; counter1=0
!(grid[5][43] == 0); grid[5][43+1] != 1 || 43+1 >= 150; x=43; y=5; counter0=0; counter1=1
grid[5][45] == 0; grid[5][45+1] != 0 || 45+1 >= 150; x=45; y=5; counter0=2; counter1=0
!(grid[5][46] == 0); grid[5][46+1] != 1 || 46+1 >= 150; x=46; y=5; counter0=0; counter1=1
grid[5][149] == 0; grid[5][149+1] != 0 || 149+1 >= 150; x=149; y=5; counter0=103; counter1=0
grid[5][150] == 0; grid[5][150+1] != 0 || 150+1 >= 150; x=150; y=5; counter0=1; counter1=0
grid[6][2] == 0; grid[6][2+1] != 0 || 2+1 >= 150; x=2; y=6; counter0=3; counter1=0
!(grid[6][3] == 0); grid[6][3+1] != 1 || 3+1 >= 150; x=3; y=6; counter0=0; counter1=1
grid[6][5] == 0; grid[6][5+1] != 0 || 5+1 >= 150; x=5; y=6; counter0=2; counter1=0
!(grid[6][6] == 0); grid[6][6+1] != 1 || 6+1 >= 150; x=6; y=6; counter0=0; counter1=1
grid[6][122] == 0; grid[6][122+1] != 0 || 122+1 >= 150; x=122; y=6; counter0=116; counter1=0
!(grid[6][123] == 0); grid[6][123+1] != 1 || 123+1 >= 150; x=123; y=6; counter0=0; counter1=1
grid[6][149] == 0; grid[6][149+1] != 0 || 149+1 >= 150; x=149; y=6; counter0=26; counter1=0
grid[6][150] == 0; grid[6][150+1] != 0 || 150+1 >= 150; x=150; y=6; counter0=1; counter1=0
grid[7][82] == 0; grid[7][82+1] != 0 || 82+1 >= 150; x=82; y=7; counter0=83; counter1=0
!(grid[7][83] == 0); grid[7][83+1] != 1 || 83+1 >= 150; x=83; y=7; counter0=0; counter1=1
grid[7][149] == 0; grid[7][149+1] != 0 || 149+1 >= 150; x=149; y=7; counter0=66; counter1=0
grid[7][150] == 0; grid[7][150+1] != 0 || 150+1 >= 150; x=150; y=7; counter0=1; counter1=0
grid[8][42] == 0; grid[8][42+1] != 0 || 42+1 >= 150; x=42; y=8; counter0=43; counter1=0
!(grid[8][43] == 0); grid[8][43+1] != 1 || 43+1 >= 150; x=43; y=8; counter0=0; counter1=1
grid[8][149] == 0; grid[8][149+1] != 0 || 149+1 >= 150; x=149; y=8; counter0=106; counter1=0
grid[8][150] == 0; grid[8][150+1] != 0 || 150+1 >= 150; x=150; y=8; counter0=1; counter1=0
grid[9][2] == 0; grid[9][2+1] != 0 || 2+1 >= 150; x=2; y=9; counter0=3; counter1=0
!(grid[9][3] == 0); grid[9][3+1] != 1 || 3+1 >= 150; x=3; y=9; counter0=0; counter1=1
grid[9][149] == 0; grid[9][149+1] != 0 || 149+1 >= 150; x=149; y=9; counter0=146; counter1=0
grid[9][150] == 0; grid[9][150+1] != 0 || 150+1 >= 150; x=150; y=9; counter0=1; counter1=0
grid[10][135] == 0; grid[10][135+1] != 0 || 135+1 >= 150; x=135; y=10; counter0=136; counter1=0
!(grid[10][136] == 0); grid[10][136+1] != 1 || 136+1 >= 150; x=136; y=10; counter0=0; counter1=1
grid[10][149] == 0; grid[10][149+1] != 0 || 149+1 >= 150; x=149; y=10; counter0=13; counter1=0
grid[10][150] == 0; grid[10][150+1] != 0 || 150+1 >= 150; x=150; y=10; counter0=1; counter1=0
grid[11][95] == 0; grid[11][95+1] != 0 || 95+1 >= 150; x=95; y=11; counter0=96; counter1=0
!(grid[11][96] == 0); grid[11][96+1] != 1 || 96+1 >= 150; x=96; y=11; counter0=0; counter1=1
grid[11][149] == 0; grid[11][149+1] != 0 || 149+1 >= 150; x=149; y=11; counter0=53; counter1=0
grid[11][150] == 0; grid[11][150+1] != 0 || 150+1 >= 150; x=150; y=11; counter0=1; counter1=0
grid[12][55] == 0; grid[12][55+1] != 0 || 55+1 >= 150; x=55; y=12; counter0=56; counter1=0
!(grid[12][56] == 0); grid[12][56+1] != 1 || 56+1 >= 150; x=56; y=12; counter0=0; counter1=1
grid[12][131] == 0; grid[12][131+1] != 0 || 131+1 >= 150; x=131; y=12; counter0=75; counter1=0
!(grid[12][132] == 0); grid[12][132+1] != 1 || 132+1 >= 150; x=132; y=12; counter0=0; counter1=1
grid[12][149] == 0; grid[12][149+1] != 0 || 149+1 >= 150; x=149; y=12; counter0=17; counter1=0
grid[12][150] == 0; grid[12][150+1] != 0 || 150+1 >= 150; x=150; y=12; counter0=1; counter1=0
grid[13][15] == 0; grid[13][15+1] != 0 || 15+1 >= 150; x=15; y=13; counter0=16; counter1=0
!(grid[13][16] == 0); grid[13][16+1] != 1 || 16+1 >= 150; x=16; y=13; counter0=0; counter1=1
grid[13][91] == 0; grid[13][91+1] != 0 || 91+1 >= 150; x=91; y=13; counter0=75; counter1=0
!(grid[13][92] == 0); grid[13][92+1] != 1 || 92+1 >= 150; x=92; y=13; counter0=0; counter1=1
grid[13][149] == 0; grid[13][149+1] != 0 || 149+1 >= 150; x=149; y=13; counter0=57; counter1=0
grid[13][150] == 0; grid[13][150+1] != 0 || 150+1 >= 150; x=150; y=13; counter0=1; counter1=0
grid[14][51] == 0; grid[14][51+1] != 0 || 51+1 >= 150; x=51; y=14; counter0=52; counter1=0
!(grid[14][52] == 0); grid[14][52+1] != 1 || 52+1 >= 150; x=52; y=14; counter0=0; counter1=1
grid[14][122] == 0; grid[14][122+1] != 0 || 122+1 >= 150; x=122; y=14; counter0=70; counter1=0
!(grid[14][123] == 0); grid[14][123+1] != 1 || 123+1 >= 150; x=123; y=14; counter0=0; counter1=1
grid[14][149] == 0; grid[14][149+1] != 0 || 149+1 >= 150; x=149; y=14; counter0=26; counter1=0
grid[14][150] == 0; grid[14][150+1] != 0 || 150+1 >= 150; x=150; y=14; counter0=1; counter1=0
grid[15][11] == 0; grid[15][11+1] != 0 || 11+1 >= 150; x=11; y=15; counter0=12; counter1=0
!(grid[15][12] == 0); grid[15][12+1] != 1 || 12+1 >= 150; x=12; y=15; counter0=0; counter1=1
grid[15][82] == 0; grid[15][82+1] != 0 || 82+1 >= 150; x=82; y=15; counter0=70; counter1=0
!(grid[15][83] == 0); grid[15][83+1] != 1 || 83+1 >= 150; x=83; y=15; counter0=0; counter1=1
grid[15][149] == 0; grid[15][149+1] != 0 || 149+1 >= 150; x=149; y=15; counter0=66; counter1=0
grid[15][150] == 0; grid[15][150+1] != 0 || 150+1 >= 150; x=150; y=15; counter0=1; counter1=0
grid[16][42] == 0; grid[16][42+1] != 0 || 42+1 >= 150; x=42; y=16; counter0=43; counter1=0
!(grid[16][43] == 0); grid[16][43+1] != 1 || 43+1 >= 150; x=43; y=16; counter0=0; counter1=1
grid[16][138] == 0; grid[16][138+1] != 0 || 138+1 >= 150; x=138; y=16; counter0=95; counter1=0
!(grid[16][139] == 0); grid[16][139+1] != 1 || 139+1 >= 150; x=139; y=16; counter0=0; counter1=1
grid[16][149] == 0; grid[16][149+1] != 0 || 149+1 >= 150; x=149; y=16; counter0=10; counter1=0
grid[16][150] == 0; grid[16][150+1] != 0 || 150+1 >= 150; x=150; y=16; counter0=1; counter1=0
grid[17][2] == 0; grid[17][2+1] != 0 || 2+1 >= 150; x=2; y=17; counter0=3; counter1=0
!(grid[17][3] == 0); grid[17][3+1] != 1 || 3+1 >= 150; x=3; y=17; counter0=0; counter1=1
grid[17][98] == 0; grid[17][98+1] != 0 || 98+1 >= 150; x=98; y=17; counter0=95; counter1=0
!(grid[17][99] == 0); grid[17][99+1] != 1 || 99+1 >= 150; x=99; y=17; counter0=0; counter1=1
grid[17][149] == 0; grid[17][149+1] != 0 || 149+1 >= 150; x=149; y=17; counter0=50; counter1=0
grid[17][150] == 0; grid[17][150+1] != 0 || 150+1 >= 150; x=150; y=17; counter0=1; counter1=0
grid[18][58] == 0; grid[18][58+1] != 0 || 58+1 >= 150; x=58; y=18; counter0=59; counter1=0
!(grid[18][59] == 0); grid[18][59+1] != 1 || 59+1 >= 150; x=59; y=18; counter0=0; counter1=1
grid[18][149] == 0; grid[18][149+1] != 0 || 149+1 >= 150; x=149; y=18; counter0=90; counter1=0
grid[18][150] == 0; grid[18][150+1] != 0 || 150+1 >= 150; x=150; y=18; counter0=1; counter1=0
grid[19][18] == 0; grid[19][18+1] != 0 || 18+1 >= 150; x=18; y=19; counter0=19; counter1=0
!(grid[19][19] == 0); grid[19][19+1] != 1 || 19+1 >= 150; x=19; y=19; counter0=0; counter1=1
grid[19][149] == 0; grid[19][149+1] != 0 || 149+1 >= 150; x=149; y=19; counter0=130; counter1=0
grid[19][150] == 0; grid[19][150+1] != 0 || 150+1 >= 150; x=150; y=19; counter0=1; counter1=0
grid[20][149] == 0; grid[20][149+1] != 0 || 149+1 >= 150; x=149; y=20; counter0=150; counter1=0
grid[20][150] == 0; grid[20][150+1] != 0 || 150+1 >= 150; x=150; y=20; counter0=1; counter1=0
grid[21][149] == 0; grid[21][149+1] != 0 || 149+1 >= 150; x=149; y=21; counter0=150; counter1=0
grid[21][150] == 0; grid[21][150+1] != 0 || 150+1 >= 150; x=150; y=21; counter0=1; counter1=0
grid[22][149] == 0; grid[22][149+1] != 0 || 149+1 >= 150; x=149; y=22; counter0=150; counter1=0
grid[22][150] == 0; grid[22][150+1] != 0 || 150+1 >= 150; x=150; y=22; counter0=1; counter1=0
grid[23][149] == 0; grid[23][149+1] != 0 || 149+1 >= 150; x=149; y=23; counter0=150; counter1=0
grid[23][150] == 0; grid[23][150+1] != 0 || 150+1 >= 150; x=150; y=23; counter0=1; counter1=0
grid[24][149] == 0; grid[24][149+1] != 0 || 149+1 >= 150; x=149; y=24; counter0=150; counter1=0
grid[24][150] == 0; grid[24][150+1] != 0 || 150+1 >= 150; x=150; y=24; counter0=1; counter1=0
grid[25][149] == 0; grid[25][149+1] != 0 || 149+1 >= 150; x=149; y=25; counter0=150; counter1=0
grid[25][150] == 0; grid[25][150+1] != 0 || 150+1 >= 150; x=150; y=25; counter0=1; counter1=0
grid[26][149] == 0; grid[26][149+1] != 0 || 149+1 >= 150; x=149; y=26; counter0=150; counter1=0
grid[26][150] == 0; grid[26][150+1] != 0 || 150+1 >= 150; x=150; y=26; counter0=1; counter1=0
grid[27][149] == 0; grid[27][149+1] != 0 || 149+1 >= 150; x=149; y=27; counter0=150; counter1=0
grid[27][150] == 0; grid[27][150+1] != 0 || 150+1 >= 150; x=150; y=27; counter0=1; counter1=0
grid[28][149] == 0; grid[28][149+1] != 0 || 149+1 >= 150; x=149; y=28; counter0=150; counter1=0
grid[28][150] == 0; grid[28][150+1] != 0 || 150+1 >= 150; x=150; y=28; counter0=1; counter1=0
grid[29][149] == 0; grid[29][149+1] != 0 || 149+1 >= 150; x=149; y=29; counter0=150; counter1=0
grid[29][150] == 0; grid[29][150+1] != 0 || 150+1 >= 150; x=150; y=29; counter0=1; counter1=0
grid[30][149] == 0; grid[30][149+1] != 0 || 149+1 >= 150; x=149; y=30; counter0=150; counter1=0
grid[30][150] == 0; grid[30][150+1] != 0 || 150+1 >= 150; x=150; y=30; counter0=1; counter1=0
grid[31][149] == 0; grid[31][149+1] != 0 || 149+1 >= 150; x=149; y=31; counter0=150; counter1=0
grid[31][150] == 0; grid[31][150+1] != 0 || 150+1 >= 150; x=150; y=31; counter0=1; counter1=0
grid[32][149] == 0; grid[32][149+1] != 0 || 149+1 >= 150; x=149; y=32; counter0=150; counter1=0
grid[32][150] == 0; grid[32][150+1] != 0 || 150+1 >= 150; x=150; y=32; counter0=1; counter1=0
grid[33][149] == 0; grid[33][149+1] != 0 || 149+1 >= 150; x=149; y=33; counter0=150; counter1=0
grid[33][150] == 0; grid[33][150+1] != 0 || 150+1 >= 150; x=150; y=33; counter0=1; counter1=0
grid[34][149] == 0; grid[34][149+1] != 0 || 149+1 >= 150; x=149; y=34; counter0=150; counter1=0
grid[34][150] == 0; grid[34][150+1] != 0 || 150+1 >= 150; x=150; y=34; counter0=1; counter1=0
grid[35][149] == 0; grid[35][149+1] != 0 || 149+1 >= 150; x=149; y=35; counter0=150; counter1=0
grid[35][150] == 0; grid[35][150+1] != 0 || 150+1 >= 150; x=150; y=35; counter0=1; counter1=0
grid[36][149] == 0; grid[36][149+1] != 0 || 149+1 >= 150; x=149; y=36; counter0=150; counter1=0
grid[36][150] == 0; grid[36][150+1] != 0 || 150+1 >= 150; x=150; y=36; counter0=1; counter1=0
grid[37][149] == 0; grid[37][149+1] != 0 || 149+1 >= 150; x=149; y=37; counter0=150; counter1=0
grid[37][150] == 0; grid[37][150+1] != 0 || 150+1 >= 150; x=150; y=37; counter0=1; counter1=0
grid[38][149] == 0; grid[38][149+1] != 0 || 149+1 >= 150; x=149; y=38; counter0=150; counter1=0
grid[38][150] == 0; grid[38][150+1] != 0 || 150+1 >= 150; x=150; y=38; counter0=1; counter1=0
grid[39][149] == 0; grid[39][149+1] != 0 || 149+1 >= 150; x=149; y=39; counter0=150; counter1=0
grid[39][150] == 0; grid[39][150+1] != 0 || 150+1 >= 150; x=150; y=39; counter0=1; counter1=0
grid[40][149] == 0; grid[40][149+1] != 0 || 149+1 >= 150; x=149; y=40; counter0=150; counter1=0
grid[40][150] == 0; grid[40][150+1] != 0 || 150+1 >= 150; x=150; y=40; counter0=1; counter1=0
Frame: 0.004000
```

In short, the conditions in your `if` statements are met *this* many times, so your function gets called *that* many times, printing *that* many strings.

My suggestion would be to rethink and simplify your logic. I can't really give any additional suggestions since I really don't understand what it is you're trying to accomplish. I don't know how many times you are expecting `print_chars` to be called. If you want it to only be called whenever `grid[y][x] > 0`, then why not use that as an `if` condition? The variables `counter0`, `counter1`, and `counter2` are really confusing to me.

Additional comments:

- If you never modify the standard output handle via `SetStdHandle()`, then you can 'cache' the return value of `GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE)` instead of calling the function over and over. `HANDLE stdout_handle = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);` or similar.
- You really shouldn't be comparing strings like that. A raw string like `"RED"` used in a double-equals comparison 'decays' into a pointer to the string. As **@Some Programmer Dude** has already said, the only reason this works is because the string literal you call the function with is byte-wise identical to the string literals you compare it against and the compiler is smart enough to resolve both instances to the same (likely read-only) memory addresses. The way you're going about this would, in my opinion, be much better served by an `enum color { GREEN, RED, BLUE, WHITE, BLACK, YELLOW };` or something similar.
- When you do if-else-if chains like `if(color == "GREEN") { ... } else if(color == "RED") { ...`, you could probably find a way to use a switch-case construct instead. Don't feel pressured to do this though, it's mostly stylistic.
- When you `malloc` your buffer, you should do `malloc(sizeof(char)*(size + 1))`. This isn't strictly necessary since `sizeof(char)` will always be `1` except in *very weird* circumstances, but I'm mentioning it since you're specifying `sizeof(char)`.
- If you don't mind upgrading to C99, you can inline the declaration `int y, x;` into the `for` loops like `for(int y=0; ...` and `for(int x=0; ...`. Again, mostly a stylistic choice.
- Symbols `sizeX` and `sizeY` are "macros" and are expanded at compile-time. You should consider declaring `grid` as `int grid[sizeX][sizeY];` to make better use of these macros. Consider also renaming them `SIZE_X` and `SIZE_Y` — it seems like a majority of C/C++ programmers have macros be CAPSLOCKED_WITH_UNDERSCORES to better distinguish them from identifiers.
- If you do `color /?` at cmd, it'll show you the hex codes that correspond to the colors in cmd's color palette. You can plug a two-digit hex code (just like the `color` command!) into `SetConsoleTextAttribute` like `SetConsoleTextAttribute(conout_handle, 0xA0);` to get bright green foreground on a black background. Do note also that more modern versions of cmd aren't *really* limited by a 16-entry color palette anymore. You can use [Virtual Terminal  escape sequences](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/console-virtual-terminal-sequences#text-formatting) to specify colors too, and the `\e[38;2;r;g;bm` and `\e[48;2;r;g;bm` escapes support arbitrary r,g,b triples.
- A word of warning: the deeper one gets into the problem of outputting formatted text, the more of a problem mixing C standard library functions and WinApi functions becomes. Especially if Unicode-support comes into the picture. I don't expect you to run into any terrible problems just messing with colors like this but just be aware if you start doing *a bunch* of nonstandard stuff via the WinApi then your C standard library functions might get unhappy.

Answer (score 0):

I believe I have solved the answer, you can just print the screen in layers, instead of printing everything we use the `goTo()` function to go wherever the value needs to be printed and just run the algorithm there. This avoids having to print all the 0's.

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <windows.h>

#define sizeX 100
#define sizeY 20

int counter;

int grid[sizeY][sizeX];

void goTo(int x,int y){printf("%c[%d;%df",0x1B,y,x);}

void colorChar(int r, int g, int b){
    printf("\x1b[48;2;%d;%d;%dm",r,g,b);
}

void print_chars(int size, char character, int r,int g, int b){ //Prints x number of spaces
  unsigned char* spaces = malloc(sizeof(char)*size + 1);
  memset (spaces,character,size);
  spaces[size] = '\0';
  //Colour options
  colorChar(r,g,b);
  fputs(spaces, stdout);
  free(spaces);
}

void draw_screen(int num, char character, int r, int g, int b){
 int y, x;
 for(y=0;y<sizeY;y++){
  for(x=0;x<sizeX;x++){
   if(grid[y][x] == num){
    goTo(x,y); //Goes to the coordenates with the selected number
    colorChar(r,g,b); //Changes colour
    //RLE alorithm begins
    if(grid[y][x+1] == num){
        counter++; //Adds to the number of vals to be printed
    }
    else{
     print_chars(counter, character,r,g,b); //Draws the character
     counter = 1; //There is a 1 instead of 0, this ensures that single characters are always printed
                }
   //RLE algoritm ends
   }
  }
  printf("\n");
 }
}

int main(void) {
 int x, y;
 float frameTime;
 
 grid[19][19] = 1;
 grid[19][20] = 1;
 grid[2][8] = 1;
 grid[15][12] = 1;
 grid[6][3] = 1;
 grid[13][16] = 99;
 grid[17][3] = 1;
 grid[6][6] = 1;
 grid[9][3] = 1;
 grid[9][89] = 1;

 clock_t start = clock();
 draw_screen(1,'@', 0,0,255); //Calls the function for all the 1's
 draw_screen(99,'@', 255,255,255); //Calls the function for the 99
 clock_t stop = clock();
 frameTime = (float)(stop - start) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
 printf("Frame: %f\n", frameTime);
}
```

Comment: You could probably save performance by using `FillConsoleOutputAttribute` and/or `FillConsoleOutputCharacter` instead of the current `malloc` path in `print_chars`. For instance, if you know how many spaces to print, you could do `DWORD chars_written; FillConsoleOutputCharacter(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), ' ', num_spaces, (COORD) {x, y}, &chars_written);`. Consider a similar call for character attributes.